# why are my sprinkles so small?

Tags: particles

This happened to me before but I don't remember how I fixed it. You can see the sprinkles' original size and as particles. Yet they are so small in the render. I'm guessing it has something to do after the render but what?

[image]

I rerendered it and now it works. Do I just rerender it next time it does it or what?

[image]

Comment: @AndrewPrice How to fix the size of the spinkles?

Comment: It looks in the screenshot like you have a keyframe set for the scale parameter of the sprinkles. Changing that should change the size.

Comment: @person132 i'm sorry i don't what you mean. Changing what would fix it ?

Comment: under render the scale option has a keyframe